# magento 2 get value of selected select box in custom module

Tags: magento2, admin, jquery, adminform, select

I have created a form using UI component, I want to retrieve value selected select box option on change.
I have created a requirejs-config.js file

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        customAdmin: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/customAdmin'
    }
},
deps: ["jquery"]
};
```

A custom js file

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
//your js code here
$(document).ready(function () {
alert('js loaded');
    $('select[name="custom_attr_name"]').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
   });
});
```

I am getting an alert but not getting any value for the change of select box. When I run the same code on the console, everything works fine. I don't know whats wrong going on in this?
Please help me in identifying the issue.

Comment: Answer of @dev_67Commerce working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento2 JS loads after the body is loaded. So whenever the page is loaded, the scripts are loaded simultaneously. You can try something like:-

```
require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                  $('select[name="custom_attr_name"]').change(function () {
                      alert($(this).val());
                  });
              },5000);
    });
})
```

Or if it does not works try using body load inside the `ready()` function.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Can you check if the jquery is working for you in the module, not via console but in the module. Can you try placing the snippet in the phtml file first prior to adding it in custom js file, just to confirm that jquery is actually working

Comment: Its not working even in phtml file

Comment: Do you mean jquery is not working in .phtml file? Or just the functionality you are trying to do?

Comment: Functionality which I am trying to do is not working in phtml also.

Comment: Can you confirm if the alert is working?

Comment: Not working. @dev_67Commerce

Answer (score 1):

Add domready for that

```
require(["jquery","domReady!"], function ($) {
    $('select[name="custom_attr_name"]').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
   });
});
```

Comment: I had tried it but  it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: jQuery('select[name="custom_attr_name"]').length check in console, is that provide any length

Comment: Not getting anything in console on change.

Comment: i said to check in crome browser console, are you gettiing any length

Comment: Yes, I checked in crome browser console.

Comment: Not working. @Sunil Patel